# What do I need to do to not get upvoted, completely inappropriate Fate Core answers on my FATE 2.0 questions?

Tags: support, questions, fate

Whenever I ask a FATE question, with the SOLE exception of the edition differences question, I always get a terrible Fate Core answer that seems to completely fail to understand that I'm not asking about Fate Core.  When I point this out, generally people go "Oh, well, it'll probably work anyways".

I used to flag these as non-answers (because they are not answers to the question asked, in the same way "I like sandwiches, you should use a sandwich!" isn't a good answer to "What advantages does a melee attacker possess against a prone target that a ranged attacker doesn't in D&D 3.5?"), but I've been asked not to do that because the non-answer flag should only be used for answers that are not even attempting to answer any question nor offer any advice, regardless of whether or not that question is the one that was asked.  So I've stopped, and constrained myself to downvoting and devoting increasingly large amounts of space to specifying the edition I'm using.

At first, I just said "I'm playing FATE 2.0" in the question, and tagged it 'fate', cause that seemed reasonable.

People didn't get it, so I started saying "Please keep in mind this question is about FATE 2.0, not third edition Fate." in addition to specifying at the top that it was a second edition question. Some people corrected me about the edition history, saying that Fate Core/ FAE should be thought of as more of a fourth generation of the system than a third, but still no dice.  Always somebody posts something for Core and it gets upvoted and I can't get rid of it and it is completely wrong and unhelpful.

Then I thought maybe the tag was the issue.  I made a new tag, [fate-2.0](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-2.0), and started using that.  No dice.

Recently I posted a question with the following paragraph at the end:

> Please support your answer with actual play or GMing experience using FATE 2.0 (or other appropriate FATE-2.0-specific support). Answers based on a modern Fate perspective are exceedingly unlikely to be helpful here.

And, today, I got an answer clearly written for Fate Core, with 1 upvote already in before I got a chance to read it.  Looking over the question, I realized that if you just ignored the entire question body and only addressed the title maybe you wouldn't have realized what edition I was talking about, and that doing that might be easyish because the text isn't heavily formatted.

Then I edited the final passage to this:

> **Please support your answer with actual play or GMing experience using FATE 2.0 (or other appropriate FATE-2.0-specific support).**
>
> ### Answers based on a modern Fate perspective are exceedingly unlikely to be helpful here.

And then I thought that that might come across as kinda mean, like, yelling and stuff.  I've left it that way for now, but I'm interested in finding a better way to tell people to use the right friggin edition.

So far the best idea I can come up with is to make up a euphemism with no words in common with any other game system title and make a tag for it synonymized with the fate-2.0 tag so that that euphemism shows up instead and people have to click on the tag or google it to find out what system I'm using, but that seems like an idea I just have cause I'm mad.

What can I do to not get these answers on my questions?  Better yet, is there anything I can do to get these answers off my questions if I am cursed with one, or must I resign the question to perpetual misinformedness?

Comment: Do you need me to grab the questions I've asked where this has happened?  I try to forget about the questions I care about that die that way so I'm not perpetually disappointed/upset about it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

NAA flags are appropriate for answers that have been accidentally made for the wrong game. If you're concerned that the problem might not be obvious to the mod handling the flag, as usual you could instead use a custom flag to point out the problem. If we decline a regular NAA flag in these situations please retry using a custom flag. Explain briefly that the answer is not an answer and is using an incorrect edition of the rules.

(For clarity, NAA flags should only be avoided when the problem with an answer is *quality*. Those are what we decline. Voting is for poor quality, flags are for problems.)

Comment: We do this for D&D answers that have a wholly wrong edition, I agree with doing it for Fate answers that use a wholly wrong edition as well.